# Can't install react-navigation using 'npm install --save react-navigation'

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation

I want to install react-navigation. hence i used following commond to install it.

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

But I can't install. it gives error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\App 2nd\Chat1\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics
npm ERR! dest F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\App 2nd\Chat1\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\App 2nd\Chat1\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\App 2nd\Chat1\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-17T16_45_15_594Z-debug.log
```

How I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder then reinstalling them while running as admin?

I would also delete your package-lock.json then run `npm cache clear --force` if nothing works for you